# list returns empty after appending data

Tags: python

sorry for this simple(hopefully) question:

my code:

```
end_result = []

def func():
    end_result = []
    data= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    for i in data:
        if i not in end_result:
            end_result.append(i)

func()
print(end_result)
```

adding the line `end_result = []` at the top of the function to reset the list before adding the data outputs:

```
[]
```

and removing it outputs:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

why is this? In my code I need the `end_result = []`  to be reset and empty before adding/re-adding information to it. Alternately is there another way to empty the list that might work instead of my following method?(if it's required to make the code work)

Thanks for the help and thanks for tolerating my bad question haha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use the `global` keyword.

```
def func():
    global end_result
    end_result = []
    data= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    for i in data:
        if i not in end_result:
            end_result.append(i)

func()
print(end_result)
```

However, it makes more sense to return the list instead of assigning to a global variable.

```
def func():
    end_result = []
    data= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    for i in data:
        if i not in end_result:
            end_result.append(i)
    return end_result

res = func()
print(res)
```

The method would be more reusable if `data` were a parameter instead of a local variable as well.

```
def func(data):
    end_result = []
    for i in data:
        if i not in end_result:
            end_result.append(i)
    return end_result

res = func([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
print(res)
```

Comment: oh ok I see actually what was happening now. I was creating a variable on the local scope so the one outside was never touched... Wow I knew it was going to be a simple solution but was not expecting THAT simple. Thank you!

Comment: @SyntaxTeen Happy to help.